# Underlying connection closed for WebClient

Tags: c#, .net

I am sending some POST data to a url for which the following code runs every 5 seconds. When the code is run, the first time when the data is sent, there is no error. But 2nd time, it throws out an exception in my `client.UploadValues` line.

This is the error:

> An unhandled exception of type `System.Net.WebException` occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values            = new NameValueCollection();
    values["email"]       = email;
    values["mac_addr"]    = mac_addr;
    values["system_name"] = system_name;
    values["os_version"]  = os_version;
    values["screenshot"]  = screenshot;
    values["current_application"] = current_application;

    var query = client.UploadValues(@"http://some.website.com/api/testing", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(query);
}
```

I do not understand, if I am using `using`, then after the 1st call it should dispose everything, right? Then why is this happening?

Comment: You might do some further debugging on the server side, to see why it closes the connection when you upload the second time.

Comment: @LexLi I do not have control over server as my employer has not given me credentials for that. I have still messaged him regarding this issue. It was working fine on local host for me.

Comment: Maybe the server had a timeout and implemented it by closing the connection. How long does a failing request take?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: @Enigmativity Well I will try to be more clear next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I am proud to say that I used the following code to solve this issue:

```
        WebClient dataUpload = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection dataCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        Uri websiteAPI = new Uri("http://some.website.com/api/test");
        dataCollection.Add("email", email);
        dataCollection.Add("mac_addr", mac_addr);
        dataCollection.Add("system_name", system_name);
        dataCollection.Add("os_version", os_version);
        dataCollection.Add("current_application", current_application);
        dataCollection.Add("screenshot", screenshot);
        dataUpload.UploadValuesAsync(websiteAPI, "POST" ,dataCollection);
```

It appears to be that using UploadValuesAsync solved the problem. I see that time need to upload the data to the url was taking quite long and this could be the reason for the error since the code is run every 5 seconds, the previous call wasn't completed and a new local set of variables and connection was called. Using async ensures that the previous call is not aborted while a new one is made.